# Simple form association custom label name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have been struggling with what I perceive to be a simple problem:

Working in Rails 3.0.8 with the simple_form 1.4 gem.

I have two models, owners and owner_types;

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :own_type
  attr_accessible :name, :own_type_id
end

class OwnerType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owners
  attr_accessible :name, :subtype_name
end
```

In my the _form partial of the Owner view, I want to have a select box that displays both the name and subtype_name of the owner_type association.
   ....something like this:  Owner Type:   [name | subtype_name] eg. [Government | Federal];    [Government | Municipal]

My view now contains: app/views/owners/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @owner do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :owner_type, :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

...the f.association only list the owner_type.name field by default. How do you specify different fields, or in my case two fields?

All help is appreciated; thanks in advance.

DJ

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You'll have to use the :label_method option for this.

```
<%= f.association :owner_type, :include_blank => false, :label_method => lambda { |owner| "#{owner.name} | #{owner.subtype_name}" } %>
```

or, if you define a select_label method on the owner's class, you can do

```
<%= f.association :owner_type, :include_blank => false, :label_method => :select_label %>
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply.  It worked like a charm. If I could ask for an explanation: why, in the label_method, did you have owner, and owner.name; when in fact the values are located in the owner_type model (I would think it would have been ...lambda { |owner_type| "#{owner_type.name | #{owner_type.subtype_name}"}

Comment: @dj_44: Ah, I thought it was the owner model. You can use any parameter name for lambdas, `lambda { |a| a * 2 }` is the same as `lambda { |b| b * 2 }`, just like functions.

Comment: actually, both owner   and owner_type appear to work the same.  cross-post ...thanks again

Comment: In a related question, how on the show.html.erb page would I that same lambda values to appear instead of the owner_type_id.  Or, probably more likley my owners_controller show method which is currently   def show
             @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
            end

Comment: @dj_44: Could you post a link to the contents of your show.html.erb?

Answer (score 54):

The easiest way to do this is implement an method to_label on your Model. Like this:

```
class OwnerType < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_label
    "#{name} | #{subtype_name}"
  end
end
```

SimpleForm by default will search fot this methods on your model and use it as label_method, in this order:

```
:to_label, :name, :title, :to_s
```

You can also change this option on your simple_form.rb initializer, or you can pass a block or a method to `:label_method` option of your input.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.

Comment: Geez, would it kill them to add that to the documentation?

Comment: @RyanSandridge It's open source

Comment: @kris Absolutely fair point... apparently I was being lazy in May of 2014