# Rails simple_form association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to create a form for 'Member' using simple_form and having trouble displaying an association where it display the organization as below instead of the id, or organization_name. Am I missing something here? How should I go about this?

**Organization:0x0000000485cf88

Organization:0x0000000485c948

Organization:0x0000000485c358**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  attr_accessible :organization_name
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  attr_accessible :active, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :role
end

  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :role %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :active %>
  <%= f.association :organization %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
```

Thanks.

Cheers,
Azren

Comment: can you show your `new` action of the `members_controller` and the whole form?

Comment: looks like Organization model doesn't have any of these fields: `[ :to_label, :name, :title, :to_s ]` so `SimpleForm` can't detect a default label and value methods for collection. I think you should pass it manually.

Comment: Solved by using :to_label method. Thanks.

Comment: By the way for the record, I used organization:references in my Members migration and if I just use organization_id:integer it will be what I was expecting using the f.association :organization. Anyway thanks guys for your help. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

looks like `Organization` model doesn't have any of these fields: `[ :to_label, :name, :title, :to_s ]` so `SimpleForm` can't detect a default label and value methods for collection. I think you should pass it manually.

Answer (score 6):

add `to_label` function to your Organization class as shown below

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  attr_accessible :organization_name

  def to_label
    "#{organization_name}"

  end
end
```

refered 
[Simple form association custom label name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334582/simple-form-association-question)