# simple_form rails 4, set automatic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form

is a little project and I try to associate patient model with consultations. one patient has_many :consultations, in my form I have:

```
<%= f.association :patient %>
```

I pass the id parameter from the patient to the action 'new' in this way:

```
<%= link_to new_consultum_path(:id => @patient.id) %>
```

And in the view I have:

[image: patient_id]

1. How can I make that the f.association field take the correspondent  patient_id automatically?
2. How can I be sure that the patient_id is the current patient?
3. If I want to hide this field is that ok if I put

   instead of
4. Is a better way to do this?
5. And why in the view shows me # patient:0x007f4e7c32cbd0 ?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And why in the view shows me # `patient:0x007f4e7c32cbd0`

This is a `Patient` **object**.

It means you need to call an *attribute* of this object - EG `@patient.name`.

--

> `f.association field` take the correspondent `patient_id` automatically

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068658/rails-simple-form-association) might help:

> It looks like Organization model doesn't have any of these fields: [
>   `:to_label`, `:name`, `:title`, `:to_s` ] so `SimpleForm` can't detect a default
>   label and value methods for collection. I think you should pass it
>   manually.

```
#app/models/patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   def to_label 
      "#{name}"
   end
end
```

Apparently, you need to have either `title`, `name` or `to_label` methods in your model in order for `f.association` to populate the data.

-

> How can I be sure that the patient_id is the current patient?

If you're having to verify this, it suggests inconsistencies with your code's structure. If you need the `patient_id` to be set as the `current patient`, surely you could set it in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/consultations_controller.rb
class ConultationsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @consultation = Constultation.new
      @consultation.patient = current_patient
      @consultation.save
   end
end
```

I can provide more context if required.

Comment: Thank you for your time to explain me. I realize that I must more research and study for develop this app, for now I think I'm wrong using scaffold for construct this app, I don't know what book can help me to understand deeply how can I manage isolated users (instances), and manage relationships in the controllers in my app, do you know any book can help me? anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You want to associate consultations to patients using fields_for, which is similar to form_for, but does not build the form tags.

It you start with your patient object, you can iterate through the consultation associations binding it to form fields as you go.

it would look something like this

```
<%= form_for @patient do |patient_form| %>
    <% patient_form.text_field :any_attribute_on_patient %>
    <% @patient.consultations.each do |consultation| %>
        <%= patient_form.fields_for consultation do |consultation_fields| %>
            <% consultation_fields.text_field :any_attribute_on_consulatation %>
        <% end %>         
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Sorry, the code may not be exactly right.

Check out the docs for field_for [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

You will also have to set [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) consultations on patient.  When you set accepts_nested_forms_for, Rails will automatically update the associated consultations object to the patient and save any edits you have made.  You DEFINITELY want to use accepts_nested_attributes_for most nested form handling of this type.

Comment: When I reread your question today when less tired :O - I realize that I did not actually answer your question.  I will leave this response up, though, in the hopes that others find it useful