# SimpleForm (Can you set default label_method and value_method parameters?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.2, simple-form-for

Using SimpleForm, Can I set the default values for :label_method and :value_method so I do not need to set it for each input?

By default, I mean a place to set label_method and value_method for all my inputs, so I do not need to set them for each input.

Example:

Instead of this:

```
<%= f.association :model_in_question, include_blank: false, label_method: :label_for_form, value_method: :value_for_form %>
```

I want this:

```
<%= f.association :model_in_question, include_blank: false %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[Simple form association custom label name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334582/simple-form-association-custom-label-name)

```
<%= f.association :owner_type, :include_blank => false, :label_method => lambda { |owner| "#{owner.name} | #{owner.subtype_name}" } %>
```

The same logic applies for value_method. So if you have a model, you can make a method called `label_for_form` and `value_for_form` which return your required values. Then in your form:

```
<%= f.association :model_in_question, include_blank: false, label_method: :label_for_form, value_method: :value_for_form %>
```

So long as the objects in your collection respond to both those methods, then you won't need to manually write out the collection in the form.