# How to create a simple form select input from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, simple-form

I'm using the simple form gem and I am having a hard time creating a select input and options for an object's attribute. End result should be like:

```
<select name="sales_invoice[flooring_company_name]" id="sales_invoice_flooring_company_name">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="XL Funding">XL Funding - 11111111</option>
  <option value="AFC">AFC - xxxxx</option>
  <option value="Ally">Ally -</option>
</select>
```

In my controller I have:

```
@payment_preferences = [{:name=>"XL Funding", :account_number=>"11111111"}, {:name=>"AFC", :account_number=>"xxxxx"}, {:name=>"Ally", :account_number=>""}]
```

In my html.erb I have tried:

```
<%= f.input :flooring_company_name, label: false, collection: @payment_preferences, :label_method => :name, :value_method => :name, include_blank: true %>
```

Which results in error: NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for "XL FUNDING":String

So i tried:

```
<%= f.input :flooring_company_name, label: false, collection: @payment_preferences, :label_method => :first, :value_method => :first, include_blank: true %>
```

Results in:

```
<select name="sales_invoice[flooring_company_name]" id="sales_invoice_flooring_company_name"> 
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="[:name, "XL Funding"]">[:name, "XL Funding"]</option>
  <option value="[:name, "AFC"]">[:name, "AFC"]</option>
  <option value="[:name, "Ally"]">[:name, "Ally"]</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Using a Hash for this is a bit awkward. Any reason you have an objection to an Array of Arrays? Also where is this information coming from you could create PORO Object and store a list of them in a constant. If this information is stored in the Database already then there are definitely better options

Comment: The information is coming from a combination of values in a constant (FLOORING_COMPANIES = ["AFC","Ally","Car Financial"] and a model in my db which has attributes name and account_number

Comment: Why not use the model then? This would make it much easier e.g. `@payment_preferences = MyModel.where(name: FLOORING_COMPANIES)` then add a method to the model `def display_name; "#{name} - #{account_number}"; end` then simple form `collection: @payment_preferences, :label_method => :display_name, :value_method => :name`

Comment: The reason I don't just use the model is because my collection is a combination of existing @payment_preferences (model) and the constant values FLOORING_COMPANIES = ["AFC","Ally","Car Financial"]). So right now I am creating the hash by quering for models, selecting certain attributes using pluck and merging that with the constant values.

Comment: Please post that code there still might be easier solutions

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation in [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) gem page is to use a collection of [value:String, name:String] so I guess one solution is to change your @payment_preferences to:

```rb
@payment_preferences = [
  ["XL Funding", "XL Funding - 11111111"],
  ["AFC", "AFC - xxxxx"],
  ["Ally", "Ally - "]
];
```

If you really want to pass the way you are using it seems both methods you are using are lambdas, it is a bit of overengineering but you could use a lambda, check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6334645/4507525

Comment: Similar recommendation to what engineersmnky mentioned above. I will try Array of Arrays.